# how to find cpu temperature fedora 13?

Tags: command-line, temperature, fedora-13

My laptop seems to be running SUPER HOT. Is there a command to ask for the CPU temp from the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `sensors` from the `lm_sensors` package.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what is the lm_sensors package? Do I need to install it? How can I use it? I was expecting a command like >check CPU

Comment: It's a package in the normal Fedora repo. It may already be installed on the system. You use it by running `sensors`.

Comment: A good addition to this answer are GUI apps that can talk to sensors. gkrellm, conky etc. Running one of these permanently doesn't hurt.

Comment: `yum install lm_sensors`

Comment: "sensors_detect" may be required before "sensors" command

Answer (score 3):

Use `sensors` command from `lm_sensors` package to find the CPU temp.